# Add a plugin from Nagios Exchange to Nagios 3.x

Tags: nagios

I just finished installing Nagios 3 in Ubuntu server and I'm not sure how I can add a third party plugin into it.

The plugin is available : [Here](https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/System-Metrics/File-System/check_file_ages_in_dirs/details)

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't mention any information about the server that you want to monitor with Nagios.
I'm going to assume it's an Ubuntu Linux server and it's not the same server as the machine you installed Nagios on.

**On the server to be monitored:**

Ensure that NRPE (Nagios Remote Plugin Executor) is installed.  Here's a link to instructions for installing NRPE on the Ubuntu operating system.
http://tecadmin.net/install-nrpe-on-ubuntu/

After you install NRPE on the server to be monitored, it's very important that you edit the `nrpe.cfg` file (most likely found at `etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg` but this can differ based on your installation method).
You need to modify the `allowed_hosts` configuration line to include the IP address of your Nagios server.  If you don't, NRPE will refuse connection attempts from Nagios and you won't be able to run your Nagios plugin or report results back to Nagios.

Be sure to restart NRPE after you've modified `nrpe.cfg`.

Next you'll need to download the Nagios plugin to the server being monitored. For example:

```
wget --directory-prefix=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/ https://github.com/thehunmonkgroup/nagios-plugin-file-ages-in-dirs/archive/v1.1.tar.gz
```

`cd` to your nagios plugins directory and extract the tar-gzipped archive you just downloaded:

```
cd /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/
tar zxvf v1.1
ls -al /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/nagios-plugin-file-ages-in-dirs-1.1/check_file_ages_in_dirs
```

Be sure to give the nagios plugin script **execute permissions**:

```
chmod a+x /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/nagios-plugin-file-ages-in-dirs-1.1/check_file_ages_in_dirs
```

With the nagios plugin now residing on your server to be monitored, you will need to define some *command* definitions on that same server.
First you need to find the path that NRPE will search for new command definitions that you manually add to the system.
To do this, `grep` your `nrpe.cfg` file for the term *"include_dir"*.
For example:

```
grep include_dir /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg

    include_dir=/etc/nrpe.d/
```

If no result for *"include_dir"* is returned from your grep, add the above *"include_dir"* configuration to your nrpe.cfg file.  Ensure that the `/etc/nrpe.d/` folder is created.

Create a new file in your include_dir named `check_file_ages_in_dirs.cfg`.  Add to `check_file_ages_in_dirs.cfg` a command definition for `check_file_ages_in_dirs` pointing to the path of your Nagios plugin and including the arguments necessary to execute it.
For example:

```
echo "command[check_file_ages_in_dirs]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/nagios-plugin-file-ages-in-dirs-1.1/check_file_ages_in_dirs -d \"/tmp\" -w 24 -c 48" >> /etc/nrpe.d/check_file_ages_in_dirs.cfg
cat /etc/nrpe.d/check_file_ages_in_dirs.cfg

    command[check_file_ages_in_dirs]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/nagios-plugin-file-ages-in-dirs-1.1/check_file_ages_in_dirs -d "/tmp" -w 24 -c 48
```

For the above, I hard-coded the warning and critical thresholds of 24 hours and 48 hours.  I've also hard-coded the directory to check as "/tmp"
Attempt to execute the nagios plugin script locally to confirm it's working correctly:

```
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/nagios-plugin-file-ages-in-dirs-1.1/check_file_ages_in_dirs -d "/tmp" -w 24 -c 48

    OK: 1 dir(s) --  /tmp: 1 files
```

Ensure the nrpe user has read permissions on your `check_file_ages_in_dirs.cfg` file:

```
chmod a+r /etc/nrpe.d/check_file_ages_in_dirs.cfg
```

Restart your nrpe service, as per the instructions in http://tecadmin.net/install-nrpe-on-ubuntu/

You also need to ensure that if you have any firewall rules in place, they **allow tcp traffic to port 5666**.

**On your Nagios server:**

From your Nagios server, you'll need to manually run `check_nrpe` against your host to be monitored so as to verify correct functioning of the Nagios plugin and correct NRPE configuration.
Find the location of your `check_nrpe` file.  On my installation, it's located at `/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe`, but this could be different for your installation.

```
find / -name "check_nrpe" -type f

    /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe
```

If you don't have `check_nrpe`, you'll need to install it on your Nagios server.

```
apt-get install nagios-nrpe-plugin
```

First execute `check_nrpe` against your server to be monitored with no remote command arguments.  This is just to confirm that NRPE is running on your remote server and it's correctly configured to allow connections from your Nagios server.
**Note:** For this example I'll pretend the IP address of the host I want to monitor is `10.0.0.1`.  *Replace this* with the IP address of the host you want to monitor.

```
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H 10.0.0.1

    NRPE v2.14
```

The `check_nrpe` command above should return the version number of the NRPE agent running on the remote host if it's configured correctly.

Next attempt to manually invoke the Nagios plugin via NRPE:

```
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H 10.0.0.1 -c check_file_ages_in_dirs

    OK: 1 dir(s) --  /tmp: 1 files
```

If you get output similar to the above, then it's time to move on to defining hosts, services, and commands on your Nagios server.
It would be cleaner to define separate configuration files for host, service, and command definitions.  But that's outside of the scope of this post.
For now, we'll define these things in the default Nagios configuration file (nagios.cfg).

First locate your `nagios.cfg` file:

```
find / -name "nagios.cfg" -type f

    /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg
```

Edit the `nagios.cfg` file.

Add a *host definition* for the server you wish to monitor:

```
define host {
        host_name                       Remote-Host
        alias                           Remote-Host
        address                         10.0.0.1
        use                             linux-server
        contact_groups                  admins
        notification_interval           0
        notification_period             24x7
        notifications_enabled           1
        register                        1
}
```

Add a *command definition* for the remote execution of `check_file_ages_in_dirs`:

```
define command {
        command_name                    check_file_ages_in_dirs
        command_line                    $USER1$/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -c check_file_ages_in_dirs
        register                        1
}
```

Add a *service definition* that will reference the `check_file_ages_in_dirs` command:

```
define service {
        service_description             check_file_ages_in_dirs
        use                             generic-service
        check_command                   check_file_ages_in_dirs
        host_name                       Remote-Host
        contact_groups                  admins
        notification_interval           0
        notification_period             24x7
        notifications_enabled           1
        flap_detection_enabled          1
        register                        1
}
```

Save and exit your `nagios.cfg` file.

Validate your Nagios configuration file:

```
nagios -v /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg
```

If no errors are reported, restart your Nagios service.

Check the Nagios Web UI, and you should see your *check_file_ages_in_dirs* service monitoring your remote host.

Comment: Thank you so much this is very helpful. I wanna monitor a specific folder in my Camera security server (Ubiquiti). I'll let you know how it goes

Comment: The NRPE server was installed under /etc/nagios but I have nagios 3 under /etc/nagios3

Comment: Ok, update the paths to reflect your particular installation.

Comment: I followed the link to install NRPE but for some reason I'm not able to find the file check_nrpe under the plugins folder. I did a find command to look for it and it doesn't look like it exists.

Comment: What operating system is your Nagios server?

Comment: Ubuntu Server 14.04.3 LTS trusty. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: On that machine, try running `apt-get install nagios-nrpe-plugin` then run the `find` command to search for `check_nrpe`.

Comment: I did that. the nrpe_plugin is installed but I can't find the file at all even with find -name "check_nrpe"

Comment: this is the list of files I found
./etc/pnp4nagios/check_commands/check_nrpe.cfg
./etc/pnp4nagios/check_commands/check_nrpe_1arg.cfg
./opt/okconfig/pnp4nagios-templates/check_nrpe_check_cpu.php
./opt/okconfig/pnp4nagios-templates/check_nrpe_check_swap.php
./opt/okconfig/pnp4nagios-templates/check_nrpe_check_load.php
./opt/okconfig/pnp4nagios-templates/check_nrpe_check_disks.php

Comment: Can you run the following 2 commands and post the results?:  `dpkg -l nagios-nrpe-plugin` and `dpkg -L nagios-nrpe-plugin`

Comment: Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                   Version          Architecture     Description
+++-======================-================-================-==================================================
un  nagios-nrpe-plugin     <none>           <none>           (no description available)

Comment: dpkg-query: package 'nagios-nrpe-plugin' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.

Comment: According to this output, `nagios-nrpe-plugin` package is not installed on your system, so that's why you can't locate `check_nrpe` with the `find` command.

Comment: I'm sorry for some reason when I issued the command to install it the first time it didn't go through, it's there now

Comment: So odd this is not written **anywhere else**. Really helpful!